# How can I get rid of cycle compile error from Hilt?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

Here's my code.

RemoteConfigRepository

```
class RemoteConfigRepository
        @Inject constructor(
        val service: RemoteConfigService): Repository {
    suspend fun getConfig(): Response<RemoteConfigResponseBody>
    = service.getConfig()
}
```

RepositoryModule

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object RepositoryModule {
    @Provides
    @ViewModelScoped
    fun provideRemoteConfigRepository(
            repository: RemoteConfigRepository
    ): RemoteConfigRepository {
        return RemoteConfigRepository(BaseService(UrlConstants.REMOTE_CONFIG_BASE_URL).createApi(RemoteConfigService::class.java))
    }
    // ...

}
```

EntryViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class EntryViewModel
    @Inject constructor(
            private val repository: RemoteConfigRepository,
            private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
    ): ViewModel() {
    // ...
}
```

And this is EntryActivity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class EntryActivity : BaseActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityEntryBinding

    @VisibleForTesting
    private val viewModel by viewModels<EntryViewModel>()

    // ...
}
```

And I get

```
ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1/Users/user/Documents/Github/my_app/build/generated/source/kapt/debug/com/example/MyApplication_HiltComponents.java:152: error: [Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle:
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements HiltWrapper_ActivityRetainedComponentManager_ActivityRetainedComponentBuilderEntryPoint,
                         ^
      com.example.repository.RemoteConfigRepository is injected at
          com.example.di.RepositoryModule.provideRemoteConfigRepository(repository)
      com.example.repository.RemoteConfigRepository is injected at
          com.example.ui.entry.EntryViewModel(repository, …)
      com.example.ui.entry.EntryViewModel is injected at
          com.example.ui.entry.EntryViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(vm)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.example.MyApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC → com.example.MyApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.example.MyApplication_HiltComponents.ViewModelC][WARN] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: androidx.room.RoomProcessor (DYNAMIC).
```

I don't know where the cycle comes from..

Comment: `provideRemoteConfigRepository` takes `RemoteConfigRepository` and returns `RemoteConfigRepository`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are expecting `RemoteConfigRepository` while you are returning the same from this method . this is causing cyclic dependency. it should something like this.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object RepositoryModule {
    @Provides
    @ViewModelScoped
    fun provideRemoteConfigRepository(
        service: BaseService
    ): RemoteConfigRepository {
        return RemoteConfigRepository(service)
    }

    @Provides
    @ViewModelScoped
    fun provideBaseService(): BaseService {
        return BaseService(UrlConstants.REMOTE_CONFIG_BASE_URL).createApi(RemoteConfigService::class.java)
    }
}
```

In this case you can mark `provideBaseService` with proper scope i think it should be of `Singleton` Scope.
For a second way you can do it like this which will make  `BaseService` by default `ViewModelScoped`.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object RepositoryModule {
@Provides
@ViewModelScoped
fun provideRemoteConfigRepository(): RemoteConfigRepository {
    return RemoteConfigRepository(BaseService(UrlConstants.REMOTE_CONFIG_BASE_URL).createApi(RemoteConfigService::class.java))
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the parameter from `provideRemoteConfigRepository`:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object RepositoryModule {
    @Provides
    @ViewModelScoped
    fun provideRemoteConfigRepository(): RemoteConfigRepository {
        return RemoteConfigRepository(BaseService(UrlConstants.REMOTE_CONFIG_BASE_URL).createApi(RemoteConfigService::class.java))
    }
    // ...

}
```